# Listar propriedades privadas

Tags: php, classes, propriedade

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
class Orcamento{

    private $valor;
    private $itens;

    public function __construct($valor){
        $this->valor = $valor;
        $this->itens = [];
    }

    public function __get($property){
        return $this->$property;
    }

    public function __set($property, $value){

        if($property === "itens")
            throw new \Exception("Utilize o método 'addItem' para alterar esta propriedade");

        $this->$property = $value;
    }

    public function addItem(Item $item){
        $this->itens[] =  $item;
    }
}
```

Esta classe possui duas propriedades privadas, um construtor e métodos getter e setter. Quando eu atribuo um valor a uma propriedade que não existe, imediatamente uma nova propriedade pública é criada. Como pode ser visto no exemplo abaixo:

```
$orcamento = new Orcamento(600);

$orcamento->teste = "teste";

echo $orcamento->teste;
```

A expressão acima imprimirá a string "teste".

Minha dúvida é:

1. Existe algum método que lista as propriedades privadas?
2. Existe alguma maneira de impedir a criação de métodos e/ou propriedades em uma classe?
3. Existe modificadores de acesso para classe e não apenas para métodos e propriedades?

Comment: O que seria esse `get_class` dentro do método `__set`? O que entende por "modificadores de acesso para classes"?

Comment: Foi um teste para o método get_class_vars(). Mas ele lista apenas propriedades públicas. Quando falo sobre modificadores de acesso para classes, comento sobre a possibilidade ou não de adição de um modificador na criação da classe de modo que ela não possa ser alterada. Acredito que isto não exista, esta parte seria apenas uma dúvida mesmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Existe algum método que lista as propriedades privadas?

A forma mais simples é com [`get_object_vars()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php). Se quer filtrar as privadas pode usar reflexão:

```
new ReflectionClass($this)->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/Reflection.php).

Uma tremenda gambiarra. Se for usar coisas desse tipo não deveria criar uma classe, um *array* associativo parece ser mais o caso, algo que as pessoas estão esquecendo que existe.

> Existe alguma maneira de impedir a criação de métodos e/ou propriedades em uma classe?

Não pela linguagem, o objetivo da linguagem é (ou era) dar flexibilidade não confiabilidade e robustez (agora estão mudando a filosofia da linguagem mas tarde demais, só consegue de verdade quebrando compatibilidade com tudo o que ela era).

Dá para usar uma técnica igual ao que usou para forçar chamar o método `addItem()`, verifique se uma variável privada equivalente à propriedade existe para assumir um valor. Uma bela gambiarra.

> Existe modificadores de acesso para classe e não apenas para métodos e propriedades?

Existem, mas não os mesmos modificadores, servem pra propósitos bem diferentes.